# Discrete movements in Phaser

Tags: phaser

What is the best approach to let a Phaser.Sprite do discrete movements?

It should continue moving along all possible values, but at the end of a move it must end up on a certain position which will have the following property: **position.x % SOME_FIXED_VALUE = 0** and **position.y % SOME_FIXED_VALUE = 0**

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat, but the easiest may be to **create a doppelganger sprite, constrained to the discrete coordinate space**. That is, make your actual sprite invisible, and set a second sprite that follows the main sprite with discrete movement.

- Make your main sprite invisible: set [`Phaser.Sprite.visible`](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Sprite.html#visible) to `false`
- Create a second sprite
- Make the second sprite follow the main sprite in one of your `update` functions:
- From simple integer division, we know that `round(x / y) * y % y == 0`, so set the sprite's coordinates accordingly. Use whatever rounding function is appropriate.

i.e.

```
sprite.x = Math.round(x / SOME_FIXED_VALUE) * SOME_FIXED_VALUE
sprite.y = Math.round(y / SOME_FIXED_VALUE) * SOME_FIXED_VALUE
```

Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/bwsgdn0v/

[image: screenshot]

I've kept the main sprite visible so you can see what's going on, as you move the main sprite with the mouse. Sprites from http://opengameart.org/content/squares

I consider this approach easiest as you don't have to hack away at any physics routines or override anything, and it plays well with any existing physics code you may use.

Comment: thanks, it's a good starting point but maybe I was not so clear.
The sprite can move along continue values as long as I say for example 'move up'. When I say 'ok now stop' it should continue moving while the property coordinates % S_F_V == 0 is not verified and then it must stops. 
What i actually do: [link](http://pastebin.com/Jype0Q1u)